# How do you create a Prepopulated SQLite Database File?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, assets

So, I'm planning on creating an app with a prepopulated database. And I'm planning to use [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library. However, I would be needing the prepopulated database file. And I don't know how to create one.

Will the process be similar to creating a MySQL database in phpMyAdmin? Like, I can create my database there using GUI and just copy the file thru import and export.

I believe there are many ways of doing this. But how would you do it? I'm a newbie to this Android Database concept. I'm so sorry.

Comment: I use the `SQLite Manager` plugin for FireFox.

Comment: Seems handy. I think I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with creating a prepopulated database.  You can do this on your laptop using an sqlite tool, such as SQLite Expert Personal.

Then put the database file in the application assets directory.  From there, you can create code to read it and then write it to a location where you want the db to live.  Once copied, open it using your library and use it.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.